# how to set maven rpm plugin to use bash instead of sh

Tags: maven, rpm

I have scriptlets written using the bash shell instead of the sh shell. During the build process I have warnings that indicate that I should be using sh instead of bash. Is there a parameter I can set to indicate that I am using bash instead of sh shell??

The rpm seems to install ok however but I wanted to know if I could specify bash somewhere?

thanks

Comment: Have you defined the she-bang-line with bash instead of sh ? Furthermore on many systems sh is linked to bash? Can you show the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including a sh-bang line as the first line in the scriptlets in your spec file (like I just noticed the comment mentioned)

```
%post
#!/bin/bash
... rest of our post script here
```

If this works, you should also set up a [scriptlet dependency](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies#ScriptletDependencies) like

```
Require(post): bash
```